# Grammaticality of given phrase

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

> I have someone like you to rescue me.

According to my knowledge it should mean that the speaker is referring to someone who he has, and he believes that that someone will rescue him. So it implies that action of rescuing will be done by the person speaker is referring to.

Comment: hi, and welcome to English Language & Usage. While we don't generally handle proofreading tasks, I'll say that the sentence is grammatical and your interpretation mostly correct. I need more context, but it sounds like the speaker *has* someone who *might* rescue, not necessarily that the person *will* rescue.

Comment: Your final paragraph doesn't talk about why it might or might not be grammatical, but about what you think it means.

Comment: It would sound more natural if negated ("I don't have someone like you to rescue me") or in a that- (content-) clause (here reduced) ("I just hope I have someone like you to rescue me [when I get to Castle Bran]").